# Docker custom user id permissions in a volume (mounted and not mounted)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**On the lates MacOS, with Docker for Mac Version 18.06.0-ce-mac70 (26399).**

I built an **example** Docker image that runs as non-root with a custom user created. This is the **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN mkdir /data && \
    groupadd bar && useradd -d /home/foo -g bar -m -s /bin/bash foo && \
    chown foo:bar /data

VOLUME /data

USER foo

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

I built the image. Called it `test:1`

When I run

```
docker run -it test:1 -c "ls -la /data"
```

I see `/data` is properly owned by user **foo:bar**.

When I run

```
docker run -it --user 1717:1818 test:1 -c "ls -la /data; touch /data/test"
```

I get the a permission error

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo  bar  4096 Aug 18 18:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 18 18:12 ..
touch: cannot touch '/data/test': Permission denied
```

If I mount a host directory

```
docker run -it --user 1717:1818 -v $(pwd)/data:/data test:1 -c "touch /data/test; ls -la /data"
```

It works without an error!

```
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 1717 1818   96 Aug 18 18:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 18 18:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 1717 1818    0 Aug 18 18:20 test
```

Now I go into the container to debug

```
docker run -it --user 1717:1818 test:1
```

And I'm in a shell. Running a few tests:

```
I have no name!@75deaf12dcdd:/$ id
uid=1717 gid=1818 groups=1818

I have no name!@75deaf12dcdd:/$ cat /etc/passwd
...
foo:x:1000:1000::/home/foo:/bin/bash
```

So.. finally to my questions.

- Why are the permissions of the custom user (--user 1717:1818) applied only on a mounted volume?
- **The important one:** Is there a way to apply custom user uid:gid on all files and directories at container execution time (running as non-root)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current solution I have working uses the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN mkdir /data && \
    groupadd bar && useradd -d /home/foo -g bar -m -s /bin/bash foo && \
    chmod 777 /data

VOLUME /data

USER foo

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

All I did was change the permission on `/data` to 777 (`chmod 777 /data` instead of `chown foo:bar /data`) at build time.
This allowed my container to write to to a mounted `/data` (that was set to be owned by **1717:1818** on the host).

```
docker run -it --user 1717:1818 test:1 -c "touch /data/test; ls -la /data"
```

Now works:

```
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 1717 1818 4096 Aug 21 20:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 21 20:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 1717 1818    0 Aug 21 20:21 test
```

I'll be happy to hear ideas about ideas to get rid of the **777** on `/data`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

A very typical use of an `ENTRYPOINT` is to have it set to a wrapper script that receives the "real" command as command-line arguments.  It does whatever setup it needs to do, then runs the actual command.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
chown -R ...
exec "$@"
```

Then in the same way you can run the base images with just a command line, you can run your own images, without a random `-c` argument

```sh
docker run ubuntu:18.04 ls -l /
docker run test:1 ls -l /
```

Whatever it is your container usually does, you'd set it as a `CMD`.

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["my-server", "--foreground"]
```

If you needed an interactive shell, your entrypoint script gets to do its setup before the actual shell gets launched.

```sh
docker run --rm -it test:1 sh
```

I believe the bind-mounted volume's ownership changing is specifically a feature of Docker for Mac, and it's a consequence of Docker running in a hidden Linux VM that can't directly use the OSX host filesystem.  There is some [extended discussion in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/), more specifically including what happens when a container `chown`s a file.

Comment: Thanks for the post David. As for the Docker for Mac, you are right. I verified this with a CentOS VM. I'm not sure how it answers my second question of "Is there a way to apply custom user uid:gid on all files and directories at container execution time". Bare in mind my entrypoint starts as non-root, so `chown` will not work... Or did I miss something? This is just an example `Dockerfile`

Comment: No, that is true, when you `docker run -u ...`, the entrypoint script won't run as root and my proposed `chown` will have problems.